# Could we migrate outdated answers to community wiki mode?

Tags: discussion, best-practice, flagging, moderation, community-wiki

One trait that makes AskUbuntu different from many SE communities is that our subject matter changes at a six-month clip. The answer for new versions is often very different from the answers for older versions. And even when new answers appear to readdress the question for a new release, they often fail to accrue the upvotes necessary to display as the top solution.

These include questions that explain...

- [... how to perform tasks with the user interface.](https://askubuntu.com/q/12493/24694)
- [... the process of getting imperfectly supported hardware to work.](https://askubuntu.com/q/91399/24694)
- [... a subject that is likely to radically expand/change in the future.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94148/)

Of course, I don't want to suggest that answers for these questions don't deserve to get rep. But I think that when these answers go out of date, they should enter the commons and allow other community members to fix them.

Could we make requesting an outdated post enter the community wiki a valid use for moderator flags?

*Alternatively*, how can we deal with outdated posts that aren't "dangerous" and thus eligible for deletion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there isn't any barrier for someone to edit a post. As such making edits to the accepted answer is something that can occur already without the need to move to community wiki.

Comment: Yes, but isn't editing the*content of regular posts forbidden? With community wiki posts you are allowed to ["keep them up to date" and "add useful information"](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/edit-community-wiki).

Comment: @JacobJohanEdwards You're always encouraged to submit edits to any post. CW became not as useful when they added edit submissions, so if you see something that needs updating, just submit an edit.